# "ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed." on WebForm

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0

I am wiorking on a web application when i click on to fetch data from database i get the following error:

ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

> ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The
>   connection's current state is closed.

I declare my connection on a seperate class as the following:

```
public Database()
{
    valid = false;

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))       
    {                  
        connection.Open();
    }    
}
```

Where i get the error:

[image]

and i call it from a WebForm. Why do i get this error when the connection is already open (I used to use odbc connection and it works fine, however the SqlConnection is not working)

What is the reason?

Comment: I see no call to `ExecuteReader`: please show code that will re-create your issue.

Comment: Could you please post the code where you are actually getting the exception? It would also be nice if you could cleanup the code you post (e.g. removing the commented out parts).

Comment: `Why do i get this error when the connection is already open` I agree, that's incredibly puzzling since there is no actual call or even instantiation of a `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: The using block will automatically close the connection for you.  It's not clear from your code how you are using it.

Comment: SQL connection is open *within `using` scope only*

Comment: @Richard i included a url for code image

Comment: You have SQL Injection problems.  Always use parameters.

Comment: Code as image: unreadable: include as text in the message so we can see; but anyway now the code in the message is cleaned up the issue is clear.

Answer (score 2):

SQL connection is open within using scope only:

```
  using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    connection.Open(); // open here
    ...
  } // close here
```

So put your *command(s)* into the `using` scope:

```
  using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    connection.Open(); 

    // command creation and execution should be within connection "using" scope
    using (var q = new SqlCommand()) {
      q.Connection = connection;
      ...

      // reader should be within command "using" scope
      using (var reader = q.ExecuteReader()) {
        ...
      }
    }  
    ...
  } // close here
```